# pandas mean() work does not work inside agg()

Tags: pandas, aggregate, mean

I just noticed that "mean" method does not work inside agg() function.

For example, consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1], [1,2], [4,6]], columns = ["A","B"])
df
```

For this **df**

```
df.mean()
```

works, while

```
df.agg(mean)
```

gives an error.

Anybody can tell why?

Here is a screenshot from Jupyter Notebook

[image]

Comment: the error is clearly stated: `mean` is not defined. Pass mean as a string : ``df.agg('mean')``

Comment: Or if you imported `numpy as np` you can use `np.mean` as a non string.

Comment: @sammywemmy what changes when you pass mean as a string? What happens that is different from passing just `mean`?